# Vue.js + Firebase - How to display deeply nested Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuejs2

this is my first question here because this
is making me crazy.
I am fiddling around with firebase and vue.js trying
to loop thru my database(key-value) construct.

Below is my exported json:

```
{  
   "city":{  
      "new york":{  
         "zipcode":{  
            "10039":{  
               "street":{  
                  "W 152nd St":[  
                     "263",
                     "250",
                     "21"
                  ]
               }
            },
            "02116":{  
               "street":{  
                  "W 155nd St":[  
                     "3",
                     "25",
                     "21"
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "boston":{  
         "zipcode":{  
            "02116":{  
               "street":{  
                  "Berkeley St":[  
                     "161",
                     "65",
                     "13"
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

What else should I tell you? I thought this structure would help me generating a quad-devided depented dropdown like [city [v]] [zipcode [v]] [street [v]] [number [v]].

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Edit:

```
<div v-for="location in test">
    <div v-for="(address,city) in location">
        <div v-for="(nextplz,plzLabel) in address">
            <div v-for="(nextstreet,plz) in nextplz">
                <div v-for="(streetInfo,streetLabel) in nextstreet">
                    <div v-for="(numbers,streetName) in streetInfo">
                        {{location['.key']}} : {{city}}<br/>
                        {{plzLabel}} : {{plz}}<br/>
                        {{streetLabel}} : {{streetName}}<br/>
                        {{numbers}}<hr/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit-2: fixed indentions and typos in json

Comment: It would really help if you post your vue component

Comment: Well - I wouln't call it a component more a hackish approach to read some data. I am editing the Topic since my anwser would be too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `test` is an array of locations, and a location object looks like the JSON you posted. Usually you use v-for to iterate arrays not objects (although you can), to access object properties you use the '.' notation, so you can try this:

```
<div v-for="location in test">
  {{location.address.nextplz.nextstreet.streetInfo}}
  {{location.address.plzLabel}}
</div>
```

If you'd like to go over all the cities, you'll do something like this:

```
<div v-for="location in test">
  <div v-for="(key,val) in location.city">
    <!-- display the zipcode object for each city -->
    <pre>{{city[key].zipcode}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach - basically you are right. Now its up on me :)
I ll keep this updated .